# Trying to stagger data on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to understand how to stagger my data in sheets and could really use some support. I've made up a bunch of bullshit data and assumptions to help explain.

Let's say I have the following data:

| Year | % of people purchasing an iPhone |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 30% |
| 2021 | 35% |
| 2022 | 40% |
| 2023 | 45% |
| 2024 | 50% |
| 2025 | 55% |

Let's assume that everyone who purchases an iPhone in 2020 will purchase Airpods exactly one year after (don't focus too much on the logic of this - I just want to know the methodology):

| Year | % of people purchasing an iPhone |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 25% |
| 2021 | 30% |
| 2022 | 35% |
| 2023 | 40% |
| 2024 | 45% |
| 2025 | 50% |

In this case, there's a 1 year stagger between the first dataset (% of people purchasing iPhone) and the second dataset (% of people purchasing Airpods). My question is: is there a quick way on sheets to be able to change the 1 year stagger to 2 years, 3 years, n years etc... For example, by having another cell where I can input how much I want the stagger to be, and it automatically updates my table:

| Year | % of people purchasing an iPhone |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 40% |
| 2021 | 45% |
| 2022 | 50% |
| 2023 | 55% |
| 2024 | 60% |
| 2025 | 65% |

| Stagger (n) |
| --- |
| 3 |

Like in the example above: is there anything I can do to change the cell titled 'Stagger (n)' and stagger the second column accordingly (in this case by 3 years)?

Comment: This questions has been bumped by Community user six times.

Answer (score 0):

Clear column B and put this calculation in B1

```
={"% of people purchasing an iPhone";index((Sequence(6,1,30,5)+C2*5)/100)}
```

[image: stagger]
*the value in Stagger(n) can also be negative*